# How to validate custom ("%CUSTOM%) RulesStringValue in Fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

I have following piece of code in my fiddlerscript:

```
RulesString("Redirect Foo", true)
RulesStringValue(0, "to the latest version", "latest")
RulesStringValue(1, "to a particular version... (e.g. 1.2.3)", "%CUSTOM%")
public static var foo_redirect: String = null;
```

It renders as a submenu and clicking `Redirect Foo to a particular version...` opens a prompt box where you can type something.

Now, I want to validate that the user typed something following a regexp, and not a totally random string, and display a `FiddlerObject.alert` if he put something non-conformant.

How can I do the validation **just after the user inputs the value**, but before there's any redirection happening? (I don't want to defer it to `OnBeforeRequest` since it may display dozens of alerts there, one per each session - Foo is a folder with many JS files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler does not offer a mechanism to validate the values of the `%CUSTOM%` token at the point of entry. If you want to do that, don't use `RulesString`, instead use FiddlerScript or an extension to add a menu of your own devising.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw for the response. I think it could be interesting to add this validation possibility in some future release of Fiddler :) Though I understand it's probably quite a niche feature.